# AWS CloudWatch Logs Insights | Filtering with failures?

Tags: aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I need to run a query to recover the data specified in the "srcAddr" section.
When I execute a sample query, the results are shown to me, as we can see in attach #1.
Also, we can see all the available fields to be used, in attach #2.

However, when I ran the query below:

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log | filter @message like "'request.SrcAddr': xxxx" | sort @timestamp desc | limit 05
```

I didn't get any results (attach: #3).

Important: the IP address informed is masked.

Can you help me?

[#1 Search results with general data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esoet.jpg)
[#2 Fields available to search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycQps.png)
[#3 Search results when filters are applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iBNm.jpg)

My expectation is that the results show me the data filtered on the basis of my filter.